# How do I download Minecraft 1.6.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried connecting to a server this morning but it said "outdated client". I understand that that means I have to get Minecraft 1.6.4 but I have no clue how to do it. I tried getting it on Minecraft.net but I couldn't find it. Please tell me how to download it and use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The launcher will automatically update Minecraft to the latest version when you click **Play**… unless you have accidentally told the launcher not to. If the button says **Play** and bottom-right of the launcher says

> Welcome, **[username]**
>   Ready to play Minecraft 1.6.2

Then you have somehow told Minecraft to never update past 1.6.2. Fortunately, this is easy to fix.

### Why is this happening?

The launcher has a *Use version* setting in your profile which it uses to decide what version of Minecraft to download and launch. By default it is set to "Use Latest Version", which means it will always check for updates and install them if it finds any. If it is instead set to a specific version of Minecraft, it will never try to update to anything else.

Somehow, your profile has this option set to 1.6.2, and the launcher is dutifully following the launch orders it is being given.

This can also happen if you have modded Minecraft and have set up the profile to launch the modded version. (Forge's installer sets up such a profile for you automatically.) in this case, not updating is because "a modded version" is a specific version of Minecraft. Forge sets up the profile this way on purpose since an update will wipe out Forge and disable your mods, which is not usually something you want the launcher to do to your carefully-modded game when Mojang releases an update.

### Updating to the latest version

You can change the *Use version* option by clicking the **Edit Profile** button in the bottom left of the launcher. Set it to "Use Latest Version" and then click **Save Profile**. The profile editing window will close and now in the bottom right the launcher should say

> Welcome **[username]**
>   Ready to download & play Minecraft 1.6.4

If this doesn't happen or the big button says **Play Offline** you may not be online or Mojang's servers may be having trouble. Make sure you have a working Internet connection and double-check that [Mojang's servers all show a healthy "green" status](http://help.mojang.com). If their servers aren't working right, you'll just have to wait until they are back online and can serve your update request properly again.

### I see "release 1.6.4" in that option. Why not choose that?

You can also set this to "release 1.6.4" to accomplish the same thing... for now. You'll get the same problem next time Minecraft updates, though. Unless you know what you're doing, don't set this to anything other than "Use Latest Version".

Comment: it wasn't set to use latest version because I was using forge. that might be what was wrong. I should probably download the latest version of forge.

Comment: If you're using Forge it will not update. That's working as intended, since an update will remove Forge, which is why Forge adds a new Forge-only profile. Note that you will have to switch to the non-Forge profile and update to 1.6.4 first before the newest Forge will install, since it needs 1.6.4 as a base.

Answer (score 6):

If you're having trouble obtaining the latest version of Minecraft, I'd recommend starting off with a fresh launcher. I've personally ran into an issue or two launching/updating Minecraft, and grabbing the latest launcher has solved it each time.

1. Go to http://minecraft.net/download and click the link Minecraft.exe (for Windows) or Show All Platforms if you're running another OS.
2. Save the file in a preferred location and run it.
3. Once you open it, everything should update automatically.