# Why is Minecraft snapshot 13w39b launching when I'm expecting 1.6.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Whenever I start Minecraft and want to play on a server they all say I cant because I need 1.6.4 but every time i try to use to the latest version it makes it snapshot 13w39b. I've already tried getting a new launcher several times and editing my profile to the latest version but it keeps saying the latest version is 13w39b!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I download Minecraft 1.6.4?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131556/how-do-i-download-minecraft-1-6-4)

Comment: @Ullallulloo Different problem that is not solved by either answer there. Since the profile editor is a new feature, we're going to get a lot of questions about it. We can't be closing them all to the same question that doesn't actually deal with the variety of ways in which people can misconfigure this dialogue.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Ah, okay.

Answer (score 10):

You have an option checked in your profile that tells it to use snapshots:

[image: Minecraft Launcher Profile Editor]

Since 13w39b is more recent than the 1.6.4 release, the launcher will obey your instructions to use the latest version it knows about and run 13w39b.

To fix this for that profile, uncheck the **Enable experimental development versions ("snapshots")** option. That will make the launcher forget that snapshots exist, making 1.6.4 the latest version the launcher is aware of, and everything will be dandy.

---

Alternatively, you can flip the **Use version** option to say "release 1.6.4" – but then it won't update correctly when 1.7 releases, since it will faithfully refuse to launch any version other than *exactly* 1.6.4. You can just keep changing this manually every time Minecraft does a major update release, but "Use Latest Version" is clearly what you actually want, you just don't want snapshots to be included in that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple issue - the latest version *is* 13w39b. You want to edit your profile and choose to play with version 1.6.4. Otherwise, it will use snapshot 13w39b, which is a later release than 1.6.4.

Comment: this answer isn't very insightful: you say to edit your profile in a certain way, but don't say how to edit your profile.

Comment: @Awesomest_Donut Well, it *was* the first answer, and there is a button saying `Edit profile`, and the OP was talking about editing his profile already, so I didn't bother pointing out where the button is.

Comment: Yeah, this is brief but correct answer. I don't see why it has any downvotes.